# Go back to previous screen after login - React native navigation

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation

In react native docs, it is stated that the navigator should use a conditional render in order to render the login screen or the home screen, based on isLoggedIn variable. This works fine for most situations.

Auth Example:

```
  <>
    <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
    <Stack.Screen name="Profile" component={ProfileScreen} />
    <Stack.Screen name="Settings" component={SettingsScreen} />
  </>
!isSignedIn ? ( 
  <>
    <Stack.Screen name="SignIn" component={SignInScreen} />
    <Stack.Screen name="SignUp" component={SignUpScreen} />
  </>
) : null;
```

In my app, user can log in normally or "log in" as a guest and view the app like a normal user. If the guest clicks on the "Buy product" button, he is redirected to the login screen, and he can go back to the previous screen if he wants. However, if he signs in, he will be redirected to the HomeScreen.

How can I make it so instead of reseting the whole navigation state and placing the logged in user to the HomeScreen, the login page just pops the login screen so the user is back to his previous screen?

This is from the docs:

> Don't manually navigate when conditionally rendering screens. It's
> important to note that when using such a setup, you don't manually
> navigate to the Home screen by calling navigation.navigate('Home') or
> any other method. React Navigation will automatically navigate to the
> correct screen when isSignedIn changes - Home screen when isSignedIn
> becomes true, and to SignIn screen when isSignedIn becomes false.
> You'll get an error if you attempt to navigate manually.

What navigation structure should I have for this example and how do I handle that type of dynamic redirect / popping screen?